# Capacitor: Uncaught (in promise) PushNotifications does not have web implementation

Tags: capacitor, quasar-framework

I am using capacitor with integration with quasar and run it as follows:
`quasar dev -m capacitor -T android` 
This means I am running it for mobile development. and I am using android virtual device/Physical device to test it.
The capacitor plugin for push notification throws a strange error **PushNotifications does not have web implementation.**
I am not using it in web implementation so why this happens.

My capacitor config file is as follows:

```
{
  "appId": "com.frmdelivery",
  "appName": "FRM Delivery",
  "bundledWebRuntime": false,
  "npmClient": "npm",
  "webDir": "www",
  "PushNotifications": {
    "presentationOptions": [
      "badge",
      "sound",
      "alert"
    ]
  }
}
```

Would you please let me know what did I do wrong to get this result.

Answer (score 1):

The capactior Push notification plugin only works in mobile phone . After implementation test it in android studio by running the app . Push notifcation will not work in Web browser . When you Run (Ionic serve) the app , the Plugin first check is it a web platform or mobile platform . If web , it shows Uncaught (in promise) "PushNotifications does not have web implementation" . You can write a if statement using platform plugin , check if platfrom is android than init pushnotification . The error will be gone .